# Extremely slow build time with Visual Studio 2015 U3 + .NET Core

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I hope this is the appropriate place for this question. I've tried other various avenues and turned up no results... please let me know if this belongs on another *stackexchange* site.

I am using `Visual Studio 2015 Update 3` and `.NET Core` - specifically `ASP.NET Core`, to build a large website. It runs fine, and if I compile from the command line using `dotnet build`, everything is fast and efficient.

But if I try to do a Build within Visual Studio, it takes quite a while. Several minutes, in fact. I cannot quite figure out why either.

The solution has 13 projects, and none of them are very big except a single `*.Web` project. I suspected that the slowdown was because of it trying to process all the `*.js, *.ts, *.scss, *.css` and `*.html` files - but even if I remove that project from the solution, I still get the poor performance.

This occurs even on a fresh install of `Windows 10 x64` with `Visual Studio 2015 Professional /w Update 3`.

I've posted a detailed log of my entire build (warning, it's an extremely large `pastebin`) for people to look at, and see if they can help me identify where the problem is. I do not know enough about the build process to make much sense of this...

#### [logfile (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/4S9NFVYX)

The *pastebin* is very slow for me. If someone is interested in helping and cannot get it to load, I've also created a **[dropbox log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c5ndwfa17bd94w4/vs2015.log?dl=0)** for you to download. If further information would be useful, please let me know. I'm pretty eager to get this fixed, it's driving me nuts.

Comment: What do you mean that pastebin is slow?

Comment: I mean that the log is very big, so it locks up my browser from time to time

Comment: The log seems to load fine on FireFox and Edge, though. It gives me a lot of trouble in Chrome.

Comment: @Ciel Did you found any solution?

Comment: if you use .net core 1.1 take a look at this issue https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1829

Answer (score -1):

Delete everything from c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ and then try again.

Comment: Can you add a sentence to explain WHY this solves the problem?  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. A common mistake new users make is to answer without details of how to actually resolves the issue. Answers should be detailed and include references, as needed. Please take a few minutes to edit your answer to include details of why your answer is valid. If you need some help, read [How do I write a good answer?](//superuser.com/help/how-to-answer).